# Connecting to PLAID through a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, plaid

Has any body connect to PLAID api through a proxy using plaid-java libraries?

[Link for plaid-java-api](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-java)

I am behind a proxy and I am able to connect to plaid sandbox URL (ex : https://tartan.plaid.com/categories) by modifying ApacheHttpClientHttpDelegate class.

```
public <T> HttpResponseWrapper<T> doPost(PlaidHttpRequest request,
        Class<T> clazz) {

        ...

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(baseUri + request.getPath());
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl);
        RequestConfig reqConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
        post.setConfig(reqConfig);


        response = httpClient.execute(post);

        ...


}
```

But I am getting below error time to time when I run unit tests.

`com.plaid.client.exception.PlaidCommunicationsException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to webproxy.xx.xxx.net [webproxy.xx.xxx.net/1xx.xx.xxx.xx] failed: Connection refused: connect`

What could be the issue here?